# Intermediate value theorem and non-closed and closed intervals

Tags: real-analysis

As many know, the intermediate value theorem states that given a function $f$ that is continuous on a *closed* interval $[a, b]$ with M a number between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$.   Then there exists a number $c$ such that,

1. $a<c<b$
2. $f(c)=M$

However I encountered contained a non-closed interval, an open one, it says: given $f$ and $g$ continuous functions on $[a,b]$ ($a<b$ of course) such that $g([a,b])=[a,b]$ (closed interval)) and $f([a,b])\subseteq]a,b[$, then show that there is at least one $c$ in $]a,b[$ (open interval) with $f(c)=g(c)$.

My problem is that I have no idea on how to apply the IVT in this case, can anyone give a hint please?

> **Edit** All we need to show now, thanks to @TZakrevskiy, is that $$]x_1,x_2[\subseteq]a,b[$$ which is that which where i struggle
>   Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Take $x_1$ such that $g(x_1)=a$ and $x_2$ such that $g(x_2)=b$. Suppose for simplicity that $x_1<x_2$. What can you say about the difference $f-g$ on the interval $[x_1,x_2]$?

Comment: of course $g$ is continuous on $[x_1,x_2]$, i'll have to show that $f$ is defined on that interval, secondly, $f-g$ is continuous since both of them are continuous on that interval, hence if $0$ is in $[x_1,x_2]$ then there is at least some $c$ in (in which interval?) such that $f(c)-g(c)=0$, which would prove what is needed, however one would need to show that $x_1$ is less than $0$ and $x_2$ is greater so that $0\in $ that interval..................

Comment: You don't need that $0\in ]x_1,x_2[$. Take a closer look on the formulation of IVT.

Comment: So I need to calculate $(f-g)([x_1,x_2])$ ?

Comment: Not the image of the whole interval. What can you say about hte sign $f(x_i)-g(x_i)$ for $i=1,\,2$?

Comment: YESS!!!!! :D i showed that for $i=1$ the sign of $f-g$ is positive, and for $i=2$ $f-g$ is negative, the rest is trivial, thank you so much!!

Comment: also one last thing, how do I show that $[x_1,x_2]\subseteq]a,b[$?

Comment: In fact, you can't, I made a typo. What you *can* show is that $[x_1,x_2]\subset [a,b]$. To do so, it is sufficient to prove that $x_i\in [a,b]$, and they are there by our hypothesis on possible values of $g$

Comment: But the exercise asks me to show that $c\in]a,b[$, hence we would need $[x_1,x_2]\subseteq]a,b[$

Comment: No, we would need that $c \in]x_1,x_2[ $. The IVT gives you $c\in[x_1,x_2]$ such that $f(c)=g(c)$, but the points $x_i$ are already ruled out, because, as you showed, $f(x_i)-g(x_i)\ne 0$.

Comment: I understand now, but what about showing that $$]x_1,x_2[⊂]a,b[$$  please?